# Can I create a PNG from InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, png, image-format, cross-platform

I usually have to export my InDesign file into an eps, then convert it to PNG in illustrator.  Does anyone know an easier way?

Answer (score 8):

Sadly, there isn't a straighter native way. There has been some threads on the topic on Adobe forums and even an [Adobe employee](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/424034) recommends exporting the image in PDF and opening it in Photoshop — though it is kind of same as exporting it to a EPS and opening it in Illustrator.

[One other thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2182567) comes to the same conclusion, but someone does indeed notice that it *may* be achievable with scripting.

**Workaround for Windows:** Install [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator), which adds a virtual printer to your system. While PDFCreator is designed to create PDF-prints (for desktop & home use), it can print as PNG:

> Create more than just PDFs: PNG, JPG, TIFF, BMP, PCX, PS, EPS

Then you could just print the pages you want as PNGs. (There *might* be some problems regarding transparency, though.)

<sup><sub>Sadly, I'm yet to know any alternatives for OS X — but I'd be happy to hear one, since it's currently my primary platform.</sub></sup>

Comment: It *is* achievable with scripting. INDD to EPS to PSD to PNG is one of the processes I have automated for a product my company produces. We do it all the time.

Comment: +1 for the PDFCreator. Without any additional fuzz you can do exactly what's expected.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little update. In Adobe Indesign 2020 now it is possible to do both things, export your pages to JPEG or PNG format, and select a specific page or spread.

Just go to File/Export. In the dialog box pic your preferred format. Then another window opens. Here you can choose to export all your pages or select a range. Now you can choose your file quality and PPI.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an easier path than that—though I use Photoshop to rasterize EPS files—but it is a fairly simple thing to script (at least from a scripting standpoint).

Comment: philip - can you share that script? to convert a indd to png w/ transparency?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a PNG for each page, simply choose **File > Export** and select **PNG** as the format.

If you want export individual items, this can be done pretty simply with a script. [in5](http://ajarproductions.com/pages/products/in5/), our InDesign to HTML5 exporter, generates PNGs as part of its output. You could use our product and collect the images, or you could try the built-in epub export and see if you can collect the images produced (just renamed the package to .zip and unzip to get access to the files), or write your own script/hire it out.

Edit: According [InDesign Secrets](http://indesignsecrets.com/this-week-in-indesign-articles-number-85.php),[Layout Zone](http://www.automatication.com/index.php?id=13) will also export a PNG of any item.